# Configure Pie Chart Colors Using Chart.js and PHP

Tags: chart.js, pie-chart

I have been trying to enable different colors for different areas but I cannot find a way of having different colors for different objects.

Am fetching data from database and then working on it and working on it as follows.

I would appreciate your views on how to change colors for different items

```
//looping through the data
for(var i in data) {
    CarPrices.push(data[i].name);
    score.push(data[i].price);
}

//Working with data fetched from database
var chartdata = {
    labels: player,
    datasets : [
        {
             //Trying to change background color for each element                               
             label: 'Car Prices',
             backgroundColor: [
                  "#FF6384",
                  "#36A2EB",
                  "#FFCE56"
             ],
             //Trying to change background color for each element**
             hoverBackgroundColor: [
                  "#FF6384",
                  "#36A2EB",
                  "#FFCE56"
             ],

        }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible to control the color of each slice in a pie/doughnut chart using the `backgroundColor` dataset property.

It looks like you were attempting to do this in your question, but here is a full working example so that you can leverage it for your needs.

```
var config = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      data: [300, 50, 100, 40, 10],
      backgroundColor: [
        window.chartColors.red,
        window.chartColors.orange,
        window.chartColors.yellow,
        window.chartColors.green,
        window.chartColors.blue,
      ],
    }],
    labels: [
      "Red",
      "Orange",
      "Yellow",
      "Green",
      "Blue"
    ]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      display: true,
      labels: {
        padding: 20
      },
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false,
    }
  }
};
```

Here is a working [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/Wpxbge).

Comment: Is it possible to mention the legend value also?